# Can't manipulate (hide/mask, grab) this mesh

Tags: mesh

I want to hide the inner mouth mesh (big round thing) so I can more easily rig the tongue mesh (narrower oval mesh) inside; however, neither mask modifier nor select/grab seem to be working, so I can't hide the mouth mesh or translate it out of the way. I can do both those things to the tongue mesh. Why can't I manipulate the inner mouth mesh?

fwiw, I had originally assigned it to a mesh object which also contained the body skin mesh, and found myself unable to directly select that inner mouth mesh on Edit (with the Alt+Z/click-through option enabled) or UV Editing mode (it has its own island). I suspect the two problems are related... not that moving it onto another object solved the issue.

[image]

Comment: please add a screenshot with an arrow what you mean with the mouse. I opened your file....but had no idea...

Comment: are you sure you've shared the good file? It's hard to understand what you want. Btw, you probably need to put the Mirror modifier above the Armature

Comment: @Chris Which mouse?

Comment: Mouth  of course

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Sorry to everyone who commented here--I didn't see these messages in time to update the file and help answerers. In the future, I will include explanatory screenshots with the download.

Comment: @moonboots Is that the preferred order (mirror over armature), or where can I find info about this? I didn't know this was a thing.

Comment: yes Mirror above Armature, you first need to have the full object before the armature   ;)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos tyvm for those links! I didn't know about those gif-make/upload tools (my online circles only ever use Gyazo). One question though--is there a length limit to these gif recordings, or are you only limited by file size?

Comment: No hard length limit I'm aware of, though the 2mb size won't allow much without considerable quality loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I'm not sure what's going on there, but as you said when going into *Edit Mode* and selecting the "inner mouth mesh" by hovering over it and pressing <kbd>L</kbd>, I could neither hide nor move it.

Then I looked at the statistics, and strangely enough, when I pressed <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, it showed all 933 edges and 432 faces are selected, but only 371 out of 505 vertices. That's in *Edge Select* mode.

When I switched to *Vertex Select*, suddenly only vertices of the teeth and tongue were shown selected, but the statistics stayed the same - but the inner mouth mesh didn't show up as selected anymore.

So I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide everything, and then the inner mouth mesh showed vertices and was selected again. Also the statistics now showed that all 505 vertices are selected.

To cut a long story short: to be able again to hide and move the inner mouth mesh, you first have to unhide the hidden vertices. I don't know how do did that, because hiding vertices usually hides edges and faces that need these vertices as well. I thought of doubled vertices but merging only deleted 1 vertex, and the selection behaviour doesn't look like it either. Somehow you managed to hide vertices but kept showing their edges and faces.

[image: hidden vertices 1]

[image: hidden vertices 2]

[image: hidden vertices 3]

Comment: How strange... Good that it's an easy fix though; thank you! I might've tried unhiding the vertices+ like you said, but it didn't register to me as a fix since nothing obvious changed on the inner mouth mesh. 
tbh, I think I ran into a similar issue before on this full model's hand where I somehow managed to hide all the faces (and edges) but not also the vertices connecting them. It might have something to do with the mask modifier or the various selection methods? A bug, perhaps?
Thank you for taking the time to download the file and answer me!

Comment: @Nintendraw It might be a bug, but I actually have no idea how to reproduce it for further testing... after unhiding them, everything works as expected. Hiding them again makes edges and faces hidden, too - as it usually does. I have no idea what's been going on there.